# Servlet.service() for servlet [kz.edu.astanait.Servlet] in context with path [/Lesson-2-web-app-hw] threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> rentForm.jsp
>
> ```html
> <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
>     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="kz.edu.astanait.Item"%>
> <%@ page import="java.util.Enumeration" %>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
> <title>Insert title here</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <% 
>
>     Enumeration attr = request.getAttributeNames();
>     int counter = 0;
>     String name="";
>         while(attr.hasMoreElements()){
>             name = attr.nextElement().toString();
>             if(name.contains("item")){
>                 Item item = (Item)request.getAttribute(name);
>                 counter++;
>             }
>         }
>         Enumeration items = request.getAttributeNames();
>         Item[] itemsArray = new Item[counter];
>         int a = 0;
>         while(items.hasMoreElements()){
>             name = items.nextElement().toString();
>             if(name.contains("item")){
>                 itemsArray[a] = (Item)request.getAttribute(name);
>                 a++;
>             }
>         }
> %>
>
> <form method="POST" action="Servlet">
>     Your name<br>
>     <input type="text" name="clientName"><br>
>     Your email<br>
>     <input type="email" name="clientEmail"><br>
>     Items<br>
>     <%
>     for(int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++){ 
>     %>
>     <input type="radio"
>      name="clientItem"
>      value="<%= itemsArray[i].getItemName() %>,
>     <%= itemsArray[i].getItemPrice() %>">
>     <%= itemsArray[i].getItemName() %>,
>     <%= itemsArray[i].getItemPrice() %><br>
>     
>     <% } %>
>     Comments<br>
>     <textarea name="clientComment"></textarea>
>     <input type="submit">
>
> </form>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

> Servlet.java

```html
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        Item[] items = getItems();
        for(int a = 0; a<items.length; a++) {
            request.setAttribute("item"+(a+1), items[a]);
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/rentForm.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
        
        String clientName = request.getParameter("clientName");
        String clientEmail = request.getParameter("clientEmail");
        String clientItem = request.getParameter("clientItem");
        String clientComment = request.getParameter("clientComment");
        
        request.setAttribute("clientEmail", clientEmail);
        request.setAttribute("clientItem", clientItem);
        String clientPrice = clientItem.substring(0, clientItem.indexOf(",")+1);
        request.setAttribute("clientPrice", clientPrice);
        request.setAttribute("clientComment", clientComment);
        request.setAttribute("clientName", clientName);
        
        
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/confirmation.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected Item[] getItems() {
        Item item1 = new Item();
        Item item2 = new Item();
        Item item3 = new Item();
        Item item4 = new Item();

        
        item1.setItemName("Apple");
        item2.setItemName("Android");
        item3.setItemName("Windows");

        item1.setItemPrice("500");
        item2.setItemPrice("530");
        item3.setItemPrice("550");
        
        Item[] items = new Item[3];
        items[0]=item1;
        items[1]=item2;
        items[2]=item3;
        return items;
```

I have such error when i'm running my server. I fill gaps in the form that pressing submit button and this message occurs.

> Servlet.service() for servlet [kz.edu.astanait.Servlet] in context with path [/Lesson-2-web-app-hw] threw exception
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:323)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
> at kz.edu.astanait.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:58)

Comment: Your radio button have `name="itemName"` but in servlet you are getting it using  `clientItem` change it and see.

Comment: @Swati, thanks, I changed but now the program shows error at kz.edu.astanait.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:58)

Comment: yes because of this line `doGet(request, response);` when `doPost` is called then that line get executed and you have written `request.getRequestDispa..` in `doGet` method and in `doPost` as well .Either change that or add the `doGet` code under `doPost` or create some function to do same.

Comment: @Swati thanks for the advice but it doesn't work

Comment: what changes you have made ?